# Rails Models: For numerous Roles, multiple User models with additional sub-roles the right design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, role

I am writing my first Ruby On Rails app - a website for a gated residential community.

The community area consists of Empty plots, with one or more Houses in a built-up plot. Plots will have one owner only, but multiple houses in a plot can each have different Owners. There are elected Office bearers with different Roles (in the residents association) and Property management staff etc. Eventually there will be user-groups (owners only or tenants only or mixed etc).

An Owner and a Tenant tend to be quite different, hence I have kept them as separate classes. Similarly their family members tend to be different too - OwnerFamilyMember and TenantFamilyMember classes.

My first design was to have a single User and a Role and an Assignment model - the roles became too many. Hence I split the User Model as above (I do not want to use STI or polymorphic associations, I would like to get it right first).

Model Classes:

```
# All classes below inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, removed other attributes for compactness

class Owner
    has_many :plots    
    has_many :houses   
    has_many :owner_family_members    
end

class Tenant
    belongs_to :house    # declare house_id in table
    has_many :tenant_family_members
end

class Staff ...

class Plot
    belongs_to :owner    # declare owner_id in table
end

class House
    belongs_to :owner    # declare owner_id in table
end

class OwnerFamilyMember
    belongs_to :owner    #  declare owner_id in table
end
class TenantFamilyMember
    belongs_to :tenant    #  declare tenant_id in table
end
```

- Tenants or Owners reside in houses.
- FamilyMembers of Owners or Tenants will participate in the community
  but they are dependent on the primary Owner or Tenant for certain
  privileged actions

I understand that with this design, the different User models have implicit roles and can have additional sub-roles if required - a Owner can be a Treasurer for the Residents Association, a Tenant may lead a water conservation group etc. I expect the number of roles to evolve further and hence I think it is better to keep the multiple User models.

Am I on the right track? Am I mixing up the wrong things in this recipe? Keen on hearing any feedback, conceptual or implementation specific that can help me understand this better.

I understand db concepts, OO programming but I am a newbie at production level db design or RoR appls. Thanks for reading through this long post.
- Jayawanth

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the Rails community! You will love it here.

First of all, you don't need to shy away from STI or polymorphic associations, they are quite valuable tools in the Rails world. Your User/Role/Assignment (join table) strategy seems reasonable to deal with a good normalized authentication and role-based authorization approach. I would keep the User model fairly separated from the other logic of your application and deal authorization using Ryan Bates' [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) library and authenticate via Plataforma's [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) library.

Now you have a nice authentication / authorization setup that doesn't depend on a whole lot of different User/Admin/GuyWhoAuthenticates models and the application is much simpler. Ex:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    ...
    if user.has_role? 'plot_owner'
      can :manage, Plot, user_id: user.id
    end
    ...
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments

  ...

  def has_role? role
    roles.where(label: role)
  end    

  ...

end
```

Regarding the other models, a good rule of thumb is this: how much logic do they share? If they have the same attributes, share a good amount of application logic and are conceptually similar (like, being a family member), then I would go with STI / polymorphic associations. If not, you can extract the common logic into a separate module and include it on both models.

Since you are new to the Rails world I would also strongly recommend that you check out [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com) and [Peepcode](http://www.peepcode.com), two awesome screencast sites that will have you making Rails applications like a boss in no time :D

Cheers!

Comment: marcel,Thanks for your detailed reply. I have seen Ryan Bate's railscasts, awesome! I was not aware of Peepcode, will check it out. Your comments about Module helped me to understand their significance better. I may have overfactored my classes, while anticipating too much of a divergence of similar classes in the future. I guess I need to be cautious about overdesigning.